# Uppy control remove uploaded file when state is change

Tags: html, reactjs, uppy

When i try to upload file using Uppy control with reactJS i have some issues.

First time i upload the file it is disappear. 
If state is not maintain then its working fine. 
But i need to set state if the file type is '.xlsx' or '.pdf'

Please suggest.

Below is the .js file.

```
import React from "react";
import { Dashboard } from "@uppy/react";
import "@uppy/core/dist/style.css";
import "@uppy/dashboard/dist/style.css";

const Uppy = require("@uppy/core");
const UppyDashboard = require("@uppy/dashboard");

const UppyComp = props => {
  const [IsPerso, setIsPerso] = React.useState(true);

  const uppy = Uppy({
    debug: true,
    autoProceed: false,
    restrictions: {
      maxFileSize: "2621440",
      maxNumberOfFiles: null,
      minNumberOfFiles: null,
      allowedFileTypes: [".pdf", ".xlsx"]
    },
    onBeforeFileAdded: (currentFile, files) => {
      setIsPerso(false);
      alert(IsPerso);
    }
  }).use(UppyDashboard, {
    inline: false,
    hideUploadButton: true,
    showProgressDetails: true,
    note: "Images and video only, 2–3 files, up to 1 MB",
    height: 470,
    browserBackButtonClose: true
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <br />
        <Dashboard uppy={uppy} />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UppyComp;
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: if you are still looking for answer, the problem with your code is that on re-render `uppy` instance is changing just use `useMemo` to store `uppy` instance